# Shifted point in PDF export on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, export, qgis-openlayers-plugin

When I print as PDF a work done with a shape point and OpenLayers plugin I notice that the point are shifted

In the dual screen image you can see the PDF exported image (left) and the QGIS working one (right). You can notice that the point are a little shifted in the exported image and I am not able to understand the reason.

[image: dual screen image]

In the image you can see the same yellow street and the point on the street (right image) and shifted in the exported image

I use QGIS 2.6.1